Thunderbird GMail setup issue
I am using kubuntu 24.04 lts. This is my first time for thunderbird. Still I can't setup thunderbird though I provided my credentials without any error.


This Mozilla support article might help

Also ISTR somewhere along the line (but can't find it right now) that setting up Google in your Settings -> Online Accounts helps with this too. If you are uncomfortable with that, you can of course remove the access to the online account later.

I don't understand. Have you found out what is the issue in my case?
